# Unhandled exception at 0x74E9C9F1 in pa2sample.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000

Tags: matlab, visual-c++, mfc, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I am trying to use MATLAB function in VC++ MFC 2012 to edit an image. I got an error when I use `mwArray`. This is my code:

```
BYTE* im=new BYTE();
ImgProc(1,mwArray (im),mwArray(img));
```

This code will use the MATLAB function to convert image into grayscale image. `img` variable is the BYTE pointer to the image buffer. `im` variable is the output image.

`ImgProc` is a MATLAB function:

```
function im=ImgProc(x)
  im=rgb2gray(x);           //convert to grayscale image
```

Here is the `ImgProc` C++ function after converted from MATLAB

```
ImgProc(int nargout, mwArray& im, const mwArray& x);
```

I appreciate if someone could help me. I have got stuck for 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think `mwArray(img)` does? And how would you expect it to do what you want?  The only single-argument constructor I see is:

> `mwArray(const char* str)`
>
> Description
>
> Create a 1-by-`n` array of type `mxCHAR_CLASS`, with `n = strlen(str)`, and initialize the array's data with the characters in the supplied string.

For an image, You would need to use the following `mwArray` constructor to create a matrix:

```
mwArray(mwSize num_rows, mwSize num_cols, mxClassID mxID, mxComplexitycmplx)
```

Comment: I suppose the same goes for the output argument `im`.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to comment on that but I figured it might be like OpenCV with output arguments getting allocated by the engine.  Something similar happens to the `mxArray`s in `plhs` when you use [`mexCallMATLAB`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexcallmatlab.html) from a MEX file. BTW, congrats on your gold matlab.

Comment: @chappjc thank you. can you explain a little bit for me those arguments in mwArray()?

Comment: See the `mwArray` doc page in MATLAB or if you have a login, on [mathworks.com](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/f0-98564.html)

Comment: @chappjc unfortunately, I dont have it. :(